# Why <s:text> tag name does not support runtime expressions?

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, ognl, struts-tags

I need to print out a text within the current `year`, my code:

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate var="year" value="${now}" pattern="y" />
<p>
    <s:text name="%{getText('app.footer', {${year}})}" />
</p>
```

The error is

> "name" does not support runtime expressions.

How could I arrange it without creating additional classes or variables in actions?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `I need to print out a text within the current year`, `The error is`...what is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using Struts2 tags only, there is no need to use `fmt` tags.

```
<s:bean var="date" name="java.util.Date" />
<s:date var="year" name="#date" format="y" />
<p>
    <s:text name="app.footer">
        <s:param value="#year" />
    </s:text>
</p>
```

You cannot use `${}` inside S2 tags.
The `<s:text>` tag will render a I18n text message, no need to use `getText` method inside it.

Comment: I do need to use getText, since I do not concatenate the year...year is a parameter for getText `<s:text name="%{getText('app.footer', { #year})}" />`

Comment: @Emaborsa Done. Use `<s:param>` tag inside `<s:text>`.

Answer (score 0):

By default `<fmt:formatDate>` tag creates a variable in the page scope. To access this variable in OGNL you should use `#attr` prefix.

If you are using `getText()` to get the message, you don't need a `<s:text>` tag.

```
<s:property value="%{getText('app.footer', {#attr.year})}" />
```

Also you should know that JSP EL expressions evaluation is disable in Struts  tag attributes to prevent double evaluation of expressions by different expression engines. If Struts find such expressions in attributes, it will report an error.